# Input field not updated in ajax function

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'll try to explain the issue I'm facing the best way

I've got a view, and inside it a partial view which basically displays an input field and a button. This partial view would look like this

```
<fieldset>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AuctionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AuctionEventId)
     <div class="lotdetail-maxbid-row">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new { @class = "radius2 text-box single-line valid" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="autobidButton" value="Increase Max bid" class="btn btn-level2 btn-maxbid @disableButton" />
</fieldset>
```

And inside this partial view, I've put this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#autobidButton').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Lot/AutobidConfirmationPartial",
            data: {
                amount: $("#Amount").val(),
                auctionEventId: $("#AuctionEventId").val(),
                auctionId: $("#AuctionId").val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#autobidConfirmation").empty().append(result);
            },
            type: "POST"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

With the intention of load the result, which is a partial view in a div in the parent page.

The problem is that amount is always 0 (default value), and never gets updated when calling the function inside the script.

Any idea of what to do or look?

Thanks,

Update: This is the generated html and controller method

```
<fieldset>
   <input id="AuctionId" type="hidden" value="3" name="AuctionId">
   <input id="AuctionEventId" type="hidden" value="1" name="AuctionEventId">
   <div class="lotdetail-maxbid-row">
      <input id="Amount" class="radius2 text-box single-line valid" type="text" value="0" name="Amount">
   </div>
  <input id="autobidButton" class="btn btn-level2 btn-maxbid " type="submit" value="Increase Max bid">
</fieldset>

public ActionResult AutobidConfirmationPartial(int auctionEventId, int auctionId, decimal amount)
    {
        var incorrectAmount = false;
        var correctedAmount = amount;
        if (!CheckMaxBidFitsIncrementTier(amount, auctionEventId))
        {
            incorrectAmount = true;
            correctedAmount = CalculateNextBidAmountForWrongMaxAmount(amount, auctionEventId); ;
        }

        var model = new BidOnAuctionViewModel
        {
            AuctionEventId = auctionEventId,
            AuctionId = auctionId,
            Amount = correctedAmount,
            IncorrectAmount = incorrectAmount,
        };
        //TotalPriceBreakdown(ref model, null);
        return PartialView("BidConfirmationPartial", model);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML output please

Comment: Well, if you mean the result it actually loads the partial view in the div, but with that value set to 0 instead of the proper entry      Or do you need other thing?

Comment: Where is #autobidConfirmation defined in your markup?

Comment: I meant instead of the helpers, the generated html.

Comment: Andleer,In the parent view, it's actually updated. I mean it's loaded the result partial view. But the problem is that it's not getting the value I enter in the input field for amount.

Comment: I've updated the question with the generated html, Amin

Comment: You should also add your code-behind.

Comment: I've added then the code in the controller

Comment: Are you saying when you enter a non-zero number in #Amount and then click #autobidButton that `$("#Amount").val()` is still zero?

Comment: Are you checking the value of amount on codebehind or with js debugger?

Comment: Firebug (appart fromo seeing it in the result partial view)

Comment: I know it's a long shot, but is there another element in same html with id 'Amount'?

Comment: Can you confirm that there is only one element with id="Amount" on the entire page?

Comment: Yes, I had checked that. And anyway, I've just double checked changing the name (in the model, and the view) to a dummy one and it's not updated

Comment: Have you tried (for testing purposes) to just `return new BidOnAuctionViewModel
        {
            Amount = 1,
        };`

Comment: I've changed the parent view including that field, instead of using a partial view. And it worked, don't really know if it's because of that or a couple or tweaks I've made as well: just retain the change of the field id to the new one, and put a var param with the data instead of creating them in the fly (both things don't seem to be relevant)

Comment: If the value coming back from the ajax call is 0, look at what the controller method AutobidConfirmationPartial is returning. Is it firing? Is it returning a Json result? Is the value it is attempting to return correct?